# How to insert capital yat symbol with EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I am using EPPlus to write spreadsheets from some data I have in a data store.  One of the characters is a capital yat (U+0462).  How do I code that?

If I put the raw value in the field, it shows in the cell as a plain old lower-case 'b', but in the edit field it appears as the yat I expect.  I can insert the symbol in Excel using the Insert Symbol button in the UI.  How do I make EPPlus do an Insert Symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can set the cell's IsRechText property true.  Then content added to the cell displays with the expected rendering of U=0462